# Inconsistent results in simulator (iOS)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm building a basic geofence app that allows users to create geofences, view them on a MKMapView, and activate and deactivate them. It is based on the Ray Wenderlich tutorial, but I have adapted it in several ways. Namely, I am using Realm to persist data and I have created a separate LocationHandler class that acts as LocationManagerDelegate and holds a LocationManager. Generally, I tried to move some functions out of viewControllers and into separate classes.

Everything seems to work, except periodically map annotations and overlay aren't rendered correctly in the simulator. About 20% of the time annotations and overlays won't be removed when they should be. Or, colors won't change as they should. Or, a circular overlay will change colors, but the associated pin won't.

Is this due to some error in my code, or is this an artifact of using a simulator?
Thank you for your help

Edit to add some code:
In view controller

```
//Clicking the 'x' deletes the geofence
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,     calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

        let anAnnotation = view.annotation as! GeofenceAnnotation
        let geofence = anAnnotation.geofence

        //stop monitoring geofence
        locationManager.stopMonitoringGeofence(geofence!)

        //remove representation of geofence from map
        removeGeofenceRadiusCircle((geofence?.identifier)!)
        mapView.removeAnnotation(anAnnotation)


        //delete geofence from realm
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(geofence!)
        }
        updateGeofenceCount()
    }
//Go through all overlays and remove appropriate one
    func removeGeofenceRadiusCircle(id: String) {
        self.mapView.delegate = self
        if let overlays = mapView?.overlays {
            for ol in overlays {
                if let circleOverlay = ol as? GeofenceRadiusCircle {
                    let aId = circleOverlay.id
                    if aId == id {
                        mapView?.removeOverlay(circleOverlay)
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

subclass of MKAnnotation
    class GeofenceAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

```
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var geofence: Geofence?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String,   geofence: Geofence? = nil) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.geofence = geofence
    }
```

subclass of MKCircle

```
class GeofenceRadiusCircle: MKCircle{
    var geofence: Geofence?
    var color: UIColor?
    var id: String = ""
}
```

Comment: It's really impossible to know what's going on without more context.  Please add the relevant portions of your code to your question.

Comment: Very tough to tell. I have very similar experiences in an app I am building that relies on audio. It will crash seemingly at random but ONLY on the simulator. On my case, I know it has something to do with the way I have implemented GCD. Not surprising since I have read that GCD works differently on the simulator than on the actual iPhone

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it was a little bit of an error on my side and also maybe an error with the simulator. I needed to remove the old overlay before redrawing in viewWillAppear to account. That seemed to solve the overlay and annotation problems. I also had a problem with the user location not showing all the time in the mapView and that doesn't seem to be the case when I run the app on my phone.